# Importing Eclipse Project to Android Studio Build Error

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I am new to Android Studio and have imported my first project from Eclipse.

I am getting a build error referring to a MP3 file (In Eclipse the file sits in the  res/RaW directory ). 
Although I don't see the same directory in the A.Studio project, error is :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':dIveApp:mergeDebugResources'.
>   /Users/callanmooneys/StudioProjects/DIveApp/dIveApp/src/main/res/RAW/cheer.mp3:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: You could try to invalidate cache and restart option in file menu.

Comment: Thanks, how do i invalidate the cache?

Comment: File menu -> invalidate caches / restart -> invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Done but Same issue . I don't actually see tej MP3 file in the project directory anywhere, should it not of been imported form eclipse? Or do u need to transfer files manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point of error is in name of RAW folder.
Please rename /src/main/res/RAW folder to /src/main/res/raw and try.

Comment: copy .mp3 file in raw folder then

Comment: Thanks but there is no raw folder or MP3 file in the project directory, maybe I need to create one and import the file manually, thought this may of been down automatically when importing from eclipse though

Comment: try to create raw folder(if it is not there) or rename your RAW folder(if exists) to "raw" and then copy paste .mp3 file in it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to rename the folder from "RAW" to "raw", it could be the cause.